# How can I use async API in dragover callback?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to prevent dropping via DnD into inputs based on a certain criteria. To determine whether the drop is allowed, I am forced to send a request to asynchronous API and based on the response call event.preventDefault() or not. This check is performed on dragover event in Vue. But it simply doesn't work if I call preventDefault after the awaited request, but it does work if preventDefault is called prior to the request. How can I handle this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are more interested about algorithm instead of code, so I will answer accordingly.

Prevent default action all the time.
Send request to server and wait for response.
'Draw' dragged object into position on server OK.

I did the same on a drag-and-drop web builder and it worked. Basically, even on page refresh the object will be drawn and maintain position because server gave its OK, and stored it on that position (in my case).